# Enforce properties of an object not beeing null

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception, nullable

My business logic receives often objects (DTOs) like the following one:

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EMailAddress EMail { get; set; }
}
```

This is simplified and I could use this class to create a new user in my app.
However, many times some of the properties have to be set (!= null), so I need to enforce them like for example like this:

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    CreateUserRequest()
    {
        ThrowIfAnyNotValid();
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EMailAddress EMail { get; set; }

    public void ThrowIfAnyNotValid()
    {
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(FirstName, nameof(FirstName));
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(LastName, nameof(LastName));
        Ensure.ThrowIfNull(EMail, nameof(EMail));
    }
}
```

This works nice, but I am wondering if there is an easier solution.
I know that there is the nullable context feature like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts), but this is not exactly what I want.
If I enable this feature, the compiler will throw warnings and complains that all fields of my class could be null.
The only way to avoid this is to list all of them in the constructor, but this is again much boilerplate code if my classes have many properties.
Actually I need a class where some properties are enforced to be not null by the compiler.

Something like this:

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    public stringForcedNotNull FirstName { get; set; }
    public stringForcedNotNull LastName { get; set; }
    public stringForcedNotNull EMail { get; set; }
}
```

So this would throw an exception or even a compiler error:

```
var request = new CreateUserRequest();
```

And only this would be fine:

```
var request = new CreateUserRequest()
{
    FirstName = "Joe",
    LastName = "Schmidt",
    EMail = "Joe.Schmidt@foe.de"
}
```

Is there a way in C# that I missed?

Comment: You could try [`record`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records). They seem to be exactly what you need, but I'm not sure if ASP.NET supports record DTOs.

Comment: Mhhh aren't records more made for immutability then for not being null?

Comment: Immutability is their main feature, yes. But they also ensure that they can only be created when values for all their properties are given (without forcing you to write boilerplate validation code).

Comment: Mhh... I am not sure if we are talking about the same records. In C# I can still leave init only properties empty. They will be null and they stay null for the whole lifetime of the record instance. But I cant enforce them to be not null...?

Comment: Yes that's true. But `public record Foo(int Bar)` has the auto-generated property `Bar` and can only be instantiated with its auto-generated ctor `Foo(int)`.

Comment: But I could just pass null without getting an error, right?

Comment: You will get a compiler warning about `null` or something nullable being passed into the ctor. AFAIK in C# that's the best you can get in terms of compiler checks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can ensure that there won't be any null values on construction. However there is probably no simple way to enforce not null values automatically during whole lifetime of instance of your classes as it would be way too processing power hungry with little gain. Common appoach would be to check values every time you need them, or only on creation.

You can add mandatory parameters to constructor like this:

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    CreateUserRequest(string FirstName, string LastName, EMailAddress EMail)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.EMail = EMail;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EMailAddress EMail { get; set; }

}
```

This code won't allow you to call `new CreateUserRequest()` without parameters and thus create empty values.

Another solution I came up with is to check values dynamically. I made two separated classes so you don't have to put chcek code into each one, you just inherit from BaseClass when creating new clases

```
public class CreateUserRequest : BaseClass
{
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EMailAddress EMail { get; set; }
    
}
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        if (!this.IsValid)
            throw new Exception(/*custom message or whatever*/);
    }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p => p.GetValue(this) == null))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also call `IsValid` property from anywhere which might be handy and you might even move it out of constructor.

Last thing I'd like to mention is default value.

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "John";

    [DefaultValue("Doe")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("John.Doe@email.com")]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public EMailAddress EMail { get; set; }
    
}
```

Note that there are many options to do that.
First is the simplest one.
Second utilizes DefaultValueAttribute which can be handy in combination with other features but practically does the same thing as first one.
Last one is example of using JsonProperties coming from NewtonsoftJson. When you have for example web application and rely on data comming from Ajax requests, this can come really handy.

Another thing reason why this approach is really helpful is because many methods especially from Linq library can work with default values like `FirstOrDefalt()` which would in your case return `null` but in my case it would return values stored in `DefaultValueAttribute`.